# How to implement reCaptcha v3 with ASP .NET Webform in Contact Us form?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sendmail, contact-form, recaptcha-v3

I can not do how to implement google recaptcha v3 in Contact us webform in ASP .NET(not in MVC).
please help me to short out this problem.

Comment: Check this one -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590011/how-to-implement-recaptcha-v3-in-asp-net

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and add what you have tried till now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASPX page put the following code at the top after the `<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceholderID="maincontent" runat="server">`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function popup() {
            swal({
                title: "Successful!",
                text: "Your enquiry is submitted. Thank you for contacting us.",
                icon: "success",
                button: "Ok",
            });
        }

        function popupservererror() {
            swal({
                title: "Server Error!",
                text: "Server error ! Try again later.",
                icon: "error",
                button: "Ok",
            });
        }

        function errorcaptcha() {
            swal({
                title: "Catcha Error!",
                text: "Captch error ! Try again later.",
                icon: "error",
                button: "Ok",
            });
        }

    </script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LfYRxseAAAAAMwj0viw_tsfmSlEyQkYxodlzaRT"></script> /*Site Key*/ /*6LerAgceAAAAAFoTUoO95pkxDqaoM8kgZVz9NdK_*/
    <script>
        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute('6LfYRxseAAAAAMwj0viw_tsfmSlEyQkYxodlzaRT', { action: 'contact_us' }).then(function (token) {
                document.getElementById("<%=hf_token.ClientID%>").value = token;

            });
        });
    </script>

    <script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LfYRxseAAAAAMwj0viw_tsfmSlEyQkYxodlzaRT"></script>

                        <script>
                            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                                grecaptcha.execute('6LfYRxseAAAAAMwj0viw_tsfmSlEyQkYxodlzaRT', { action: 'contact_us' }).then(function (token) { //6LerAgceAAAAAFoTUoO95pkxDqaoM8kgZVz9NdK_//

                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "Default.aspx/SetToken",
                                        data: JSON.stringify({ _token: token }),
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function (response) {
                                            console.log('Passed the token successfully');
                                        },
                                        failure: function (response) {
                                            alert(response.d);
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        </script>

                        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

And now see the below code for ASPX.CS page for the actions.

```cs
using App.BAL.Master;
using App.BAL.Utility;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Supplychain_cms.contact
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string recaptchaSecret = "6LfYRxseAAAAAKu__YvhSPEQVJBVunOeeutWN8ro";  /*Secret Key --- 6LerAgceAAAAAM7gGAKouqHnz7w9KwrI25OnIjyw*/
        private string Token = string.Empty;
        private ResponseToken response = new ResponseToken();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_Submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (CaptchaVerify().Success)
                {
                    string to_username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["to_username"].ToString();
                    string form_username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["form_username"].ToString();
                    string form_password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["form_password"].ToString();
                    string smtpAddress = "smtppro.zoho.in";
                    int portNumber = 587;
                    bool enableSSL = true;

                    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                    {

                        string template = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/main-assets/components/contactmail.html"));
                        template = template.Replace("FULLNAME", txt_Name.Value);
                        template = template.Replace("EMAILID", txt_Email.Value);
                        template = template.Replace("MESSAGE", txt_Message.Value);

                        mail.From = new MailAddress(form_username, "Supply Chain");
                        mail.To.Add(to_username);
                        mail.Subject = "New appointment query from " + txt_Name.Value + " for SuplyChain";
                        mail.Body = template.ToString();
                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
                        {
                            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(form_username, Encrypt.Decryptdata(form_password));
                            smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                            smtp.Send(mail);
                        }
                    }

                    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                    {

                        string template = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/main-assets/components/contactreply.html"));
                        template = template.Replace("FULLNAME", txt_Name.Value);


                        mail.From = new MailAddress(form_username, "Supply Chain");
                        mail.To.Add(txt_Email.Value);
                        mail.Subject = "Thank you for contacting on Supply Chain";
                        mail.Body = template.ToString();
                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
                        {
                            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(form_username, Encrypt.Decryptdata(form_password));
                            smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                            smtp.Send(mail);
                        }
                    }


                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", "popup();", true);
                    txt_Name.Value = "";
                    txt_Email.Value = "";
                    txt_Message.Value = "";

                }
                else
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", "errorcaptcha();", true);
                    txt_Name.Value = "";
                    txt_Email.Value = "";
                    txt_Message.Value = "";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popupservererror", "popupservererror(); console.log('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
            }
        }


        public ResponseToken CaptchaVerify()
        {
            //It should only call once
            if (response.score == 0)
            {
                Token = hf_token.Value;
                var responseString = RecaptchaVerify(Token);
                response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseToken>(responseString.Result);

            }
            return response;


        }
        private string apiAddress = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";


        private async Task<string> RecaptchaVerify(string recaptchaToken)
        {
            string url = $"{apiAddress}?secret={recaptchaSecret}&response={recaptchaToken}";
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {

                    string responseString = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
                    return responseString;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }


        public class ResponseToken
        {

            public DateTime challenge_ts { get; set; }
            public float score { get; set; }
            public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }
            public bool Success { get; set; }
            public string hostname { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now go the Web.config file for Database connection.

```xml
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="CON_NAME" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; 
        Initial Catalog=db_SUPPLY_CHAIN; User ID=sa; 
        Password=jagannath29" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @WiktorZychla Can you explain please ?