# reCAPTCHA v3 token generation after submitting form in ASP.NET Core using Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to specifically implement the action of only setting the token value once the form is submitted, instead of setting the value on page load and resetting the token every 90 seconds or so before the token expiration.
These two stackoverflow questions don't help in that regard, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590011/how-to-implement-recaptcha-v3-in-asp-net) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507695/google-recaptcha-v3-example-demo?noredirect=1&lq=1).

for example, here is my form:

```
<form id="contact" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Token" />
    <p><label asp-for="Name">Name</label> <input type="text" asp-for="Name" required /></p>
    <p><label asp-for="Company">Company</label> <input type="text" asp-for="Company" /></p>
    <p><label asp-for="EmailAddress">Email</label> <input type="email" asp-for="EmailAddress" required /></p>
    <p><label asp-for="PhoneNumber">Phone</label> <input type="tel" asp-for="PhoneNumber" required /></p>
    <p><label asp-for="Message">Message</label> <textarea asp-for="Message" required></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

I have tried to `preventDefault` on the form submission then call either `submit` or `requestSubmit` on the form after the token is loaded and both instances will lead to an `Antiforgery token validation failed` issue as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0). For my JS part, I am waiting for ready to load the library, then I will use that to bind listeners to the form submit event, then execute when form is submitted:

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("contact").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.execute("@Model.reCaptchaSiteKey", {action: "contact"}).then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById("Token").value = token;
            document.getElementById("contact").requestSubmit((document.getElementById("submit"));
        });
    });
});
```

I have also tried to disable the antiforgery request verification using the form attribute `asp-antiforgery="false"` but through more reading figured this shouldnt be done as there is [no good reason too](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification).

How can I achieve this

**EDIT**
even setting the form attribute `asp-antiforgery="false"`, I still get the following error.

> Antiforgery token validation failed. The required antiforgery request token was not provided in either form field "__RequestVerificationToken" or header value "RequestVerificationToken".

**UPDATE** 
To clarify, I can get this to work no problem by generating a token upon page load and refreshing to token every 90 seconds as shown in the code below. But, I do not want to go this route. Is there not a way to only add the value of the token after submission?

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute("@Model.reCaptchaSiteKey", {action: "submit"}).then(function(token) {
        document.getElementById("Token").value = token;
    });
});
setInterval(() => {
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute("@Model.reCaptchaSiteKey", {action: "submit"}).then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById("Token").value = token;
        });
    });
}, 90 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To close this issue**
I have got this working, the issue was that I was preventing the default action of the form when pressing the input button to submit it. When doing so, the data in the form was still sent to the backend and thus, it didnt matter if I added the token value after since the backend was already populated with the Token being blank.
To fix this, I prevented the default action of the input button on click, then added the token value, and then resubmitted the form with the input as the `submitter` as shown below:

```
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        let form = document.getElementById("contact");
        let submitBtn = document.getElementById("sub-btn");
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            grecaptcha.execute("@Model.reCaptchaSiteKey", {action: "contact"}).then(function(token) {
                document.getElementById("Token").value = token;
                form.requestSubmit(submitBtn);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

With the input button on the form as follows:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" id="sub-btn" /></p>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @Duke3e33 but I adjusted your solution a bit to fix my problem:


<script>
    function getToken() {
  YOUR SOLUTION
 }

 function pageLoad() {
  if ("@Model.isRecaptchaActive' == 'True') {
   getToken();
  }
 }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are simply using a generic form (Snippet from your example below)

```html
<form id="contact" method="post">
```

The [ASP.NET Core Automatic Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-form-tag-helper) addition of the AntiForgery token isn't happening. (You can validate this theory by viewing source and looking for the AntiForgery token)

If you don't utilize the tag helper using `asp-` style elements on the form tag you will need to add a validation token manually using something like this

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: When I view the source, the AntiForgery token is there. From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0) documentation, the automatic generation of antiforgery tokens happens based on my form. As an example, The reCAPTCHA will work if I set the token right away upon page load, and I wont have any `Antiforgery` issues