# Recaptcha user verified bug query

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, recaptcha

I am trying to insert the captcha and button but is going to and continue to next page without verification
Here is my html:

```
    <form method="POST">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my site key"></div>
<button name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Here is my attempt in php:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$url='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$privatekey='my key';
$response=file_get_contents($url.'?secret='.$privatekey.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remote'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$data=json_decode($response);
if (isset($data->success) AND $data==true) {
echo 'location:files/index.php';
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: perhaps `header("Location:  files/index.php");` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Verify Google Recaptcha V3 Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405977/how-to-verify-google-recaptcha-v3-response)