# ReCaptcha3: How to call execute when user takes the action?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha-v3

I managed to get ReCaptcha3 working when including it like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=mykey"></script>
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('mykey', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
       document.getElementById("googletoken").value= token;
    });
</script>
```

However, in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) I found the following note:

> Note: reCAPTCHA tokens expire after two minutes. If you're protecting an action with reCAPTCHA, make sure to call execute when the user takes the action.

Since I use the reCAPTCHA on a contact form, its likely that a user will take more then two minutes to write something.

Therefore, I tried to execute the key on submit (the alerts are only for testing):

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=mykey"></script>
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      document.getElementById('contactform').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        alert('hi');
        grecaptcha.execute('mykey', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
           alert('Iam invisible');
           document.getElementById("googletoken").value= token;
        });
      }, false);
  });
</script>
```

Now "Hi" is promted, but "Iam invisible" won't show up. Thus, it I get a `missing-input-response` on the server side. Why is `then` not fired inside `addEventListener`?

Comment: what are say your console log? is there a call to google?
Do you set your key in "mykey"?

Comment: @db1975 it seems that `grecaptcha.execute` is not executed and the form is submitted. I have set the key properly, the first top version is working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the form is submitted before the async call `grecaptcha.execute` is complete. To fix the issue, one need to submit it manually:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=mykey"></script>
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      document.getElementById('contactform').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        grecaptcha.execute('mykey', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {

           document.getElementById("googletoken").value= token; 
           document.getElementById('contactform').submit();
        });

      }, false);

  });
</script>
```