recaptcha v3 token is always null when domain is entered but ip
for solution:
Automatically bind the challenge to a button
my application works as expected but
Programmatically invoke the challenge
token is always null.
simply I applied this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067347/492258
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=mykey"></script>
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      document.getElementById('contactform').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        grecaptcha.execute('mykey', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {

           document.getElementById("googletoken").value= token; 
           document.getElementById('contactform').submit();
        });

      }, false);

  });
</script>

when I used ip such as
127.0.0.1 or prod ip
token returned is non empty string.
but on domain  such as
localhost or prod domain
it is always null.

My bad, appereanlty I am using V2 invisible which made me think it was V3.
When I created new keys for V3, it worked as expected.
