# Count/identify INCORRECT selection in reCaptcha v3

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

I want to use the 'reCaptcha v3 invisible option' where you don’t have to do any particular action like clicking on *'I am not a robot'*.

[image]

I want to know how many API calls are made in each of the following scenarios

> 1. Form is submitted and no prompt is shown by reCaptcha because it considers as a human. not a bot.
> 2. Form is submitted and ReCaptcha shows the puzzle to solve because it considers probably spam, the user makes the correct selection.
> 3. In the above scenario (2), the user makes an incorrect selection.

**Question:** How to track/detect/identify the no 3 above?

**What I have done so far**

I studied the following answer. (*It was better than the official Google documentation*)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57202461/18752911

I went through the official reCaptcha v3 documentation too.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit the reCaptcha admin console and view/download the statistics. See the below image of the downloaded CSV. (No.3 - Unsuccessful attempts are included too.)

[Image of CSV with reCaptcha analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vkmn.png)

More information about analytics: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/analytics#recaptcha_v3

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to get these stats in the browser via JavaScript? (I mean when those events actually happen in real-time)